# How do I detect when a row or multiple rows are selected in my NSTableView ?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I need to check a checkbox column field when a row in my NSTableView has been selected.

How do I detect when a row or multiple rows are selected in my NSTableView ?

thanks

Comment: I would advise that you expand your question because you're not providing enough information for anyone to realistically help you. This usually leads to a protracted and frustrating round of requests in the comments for more information by other users who **really do want to help you**. For example, include in the question: code snippets/samples, the API you're using, stack traces, screen shots etc. When you've done this, flag to have your question re-opened. Please also take the time to [read this](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints). Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use notification `NSTableViewSelectionIsChangingNotification`. whenever this notification comes in your application `performclick` on checkbox.
create and connect `-(IBAction)checkBoxMethod :(id)sender` method to check box and write your code in that function.
[CheckBox in tableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021346/checkbox-in-tableview)
[How to click a checkbox in nstableview and update an object using KVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742441/how-to-click-a-checkbox-in-nstableview-and-update-an-object-using-kvc)
[NSTableView with Checkbox Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433495/nstableview-with-checkbox-cell)